# Executing Multiple Hive Queries Parallely

Tags: php, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am developing a web based analytical tool using php,Hadoop/Hive(**single node Hadoop cluster-cloudera vm,8 CPU 4 GB RAM**),Thrift API. Hive thrift API runs Hive queries sequentially which takes ample of time for execution. I am trying to use multithreading approach for these hive queries so they can execute parallely and save execution time.

I have changed default value of "**mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum**" to **20** and "**mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum**" to **20** in **conf/mapred-site.xml** file.
I have also changed default value of "**hive.exec.parallel**" to **true** in **conf/hive-site.xml**.

I am able to run 4 hive queries parallely using **PHP "curl_multi_exec"** but it is taking infinite execution time for 5 parallel hive queries. After making previously mentioned changes I am still getting same result.

I am able to execute 4 queries parallely but not 5.

So, here what I am doing wrong?
Why it is working perfectly for 4 parallel queries but not for 5 parallel queries?
Do I need to make any other changes in configuration files?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?